# DynamoDB : List all partition keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I want to update contains in DynamoDB, for which I need to iterate over existing partition keys present in table.
Is there any way to fetch only list of partition keys using Python. Scan and Query only work on attributes of my table. Is there any way to get all partition key for table ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your table uses sort keys in addition to the partition keys (stated differently, if the keys are composite of partition + sort key) then the answer is: no - there is no way to query or scan for just the partition keys. To clarify, you can still scan your table with a projection that returns the keys only, but it will return each primary key multiple times, once for each item that has the same primary key with a different sort key.

If your table schema uses partition keys only (no sort key) then you can write a scan with a projection of only the primary key and therefore, get the list of partition keys as a result.

Comment: Well, as I mentioned in the answer, there is no way to query just for distinct partition keys. You have to scan to determine the keys.

Comment: It worked with projection, i am able to retrieve only partition keys suing that - Thanks

Comment: Here there is something important to note, that you can NOT query just for partition keys either, distinct or not.

Comment: Some years after AWS has published some smart techniques how to list all partition keys in a more efficient way: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/generate-a-distinct-set-of-partition-keys-for-an-amazon-dynamodb-table-efficiently/

Answer (score 2):

### Overview

To gain all of the partition keys from a table you need to use [`Scan`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html) which will read all of the items in the table. As you are only wanting keys returned, you can use the [`ProjectionExpression`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#DDB-Scan-request-ProjectionExpression) parameter to specify which attributes you would like to be returned.

**Scan**

*The Scan operation returns one or more items and item attributes by accessing every item in a table or a secondary index. To have DynamoDB return fewer items, you can provide a FilterExpression operation.*

**ProjectionExpression**

*A string that identifies one or more attributes to retrieve from the specified table or index. These attributes can include scalars, sets, or elements of a JSON document. The attributes in the expression must be separated by commas.If no attribute names are specified, then all attributes will be returned. If any of the requested attributes are not found, they will not appear in the result.*

---

### Solution

###### My Table

| pk | sk | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | abc | data | data | data |
| 456 | def | data | data | data |
| 789 | ghi | data | data | data |

###### Scan with ProjectionExpression

```
aws dynamodb scan \
    --table-name MusicCollection \
    --projection-expression "pk, sk"
```

###### Response

| pk | sk |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | abc |
| 456 | def |
| 789 | ghi |