# Get List of All Partition Keys from DynamoDB Table in c#

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to find a way to create a list in c# of only the partition keys in a dynamodb table. There are no duplicates in the partition keys (so no sort key) and I am not interested in returning any of the other information in the row. Is there a way I can query for the partition keys and drop them into a List?

I have found plenty of answers that return the entire table information, but I only need the partition keys. This question ([DynamoDB : List all partition keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48689474/dynamodb-list-all-partition-keys)) states that it can be done but did not provide a code sample and I am struggling to figure it out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a [`Scan`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html) and provide [`AttributesToGet`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#DDB-Scan-request-AttributesToGet) or [`ProjectionExpression`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#DDB-Scan-request-ProjectionExpression)

```
string tableName = "Thread";
Table ThreadTable = Table.LoadTable(client, tableName);

ScanOperationConfig config = new ScanOperationConfig()
{
  AttributesToGet = new List<string> { "pk" } 
};

Search search = ThreadTable.Scan(config);
```